# How to correctly close the EventHubReceiver when working with Azure IoT in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I am writing an application that should be able to read and display IoT data. The basic functionality works for me with this code (I removed some checks etc so that the code would the shorter):

```
public void Run()
{
    _eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, "messages/events");
    var partitions = _eventHubClient.GetRuntimeInformation().PartitionIds;
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var tasks = partitions.Select(partition => ReceiveMessagesFromDeviceAsync(partition, cts.Token));
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

public void Cancel()
{
    cts.Cancel();
}

private async Task ReceiveMessagesFromDeviceAsync(string partition, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var eventHubReceiver = _eventHubClient.GetDefaultConsumerGroup().CreateReceiver(partition, DateTime.UtcNow);
    while (true)
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }
        var eventData = await eventHubReceiver.ReceiveAsync(new TimeSpan(0,0,1));

        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());
        Console.WriteLine("Message received at {2}. Partition: {0} Data: '{1}'", partition, data, eventData.EnqueuedTimeUtc);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I need to be able to stop and restart the connection again. Everything works okay until the moment when I start it for the 6th time, then I get the "QuotaExceededException": "Exceeded the maximum number of allowed receivers per partition in a consumer group which is 5". I have googled the exception and I understand the problem, what I don't know is how to correctly close the previous receivers after I close a connection, so that I could open it again later. I have tried calling

```
eventHubReceiver.Close()
```

in the Cancel() method but it didn't seem to help.

I would be very grateful for any hints on how to solve this, thanks.

Comment: I may be missing some context around the end-to-end scenario, so please forgive me if there are reasons that I'm not seeing.   I'm not sure that you're using the best tools for the job in this case.  Have you considered using the Event Processor Client rather than a partition receiver?  Reading data from all partitions of an Event Hub with the ability to Start/Stop on demand fits its core mission well.

Comment: Honestly, this is a few years old project I took over after another developer so it is very well possible that there are much better approaches how to do this. Thanks for the tip which tools I should look into.

Comment: When you close the receiver, it closes out the AMQP link to the service and should stop counting against the limit.  There is some potential latency in that sequence of events, so if you're closing/creating in quick succession, whether on the same machine or not, you could see some errors until the service state catches up.   Typically, you'd want to create the receiver and treat it as a long-lived client.  Is the Run tied to the lifespan of the process for the application or is it being called periodically?

Comment: The other thing that I notice is that you mention closing the receiver but you're also creating an EventHubClient in that same Run scope; are you closing the client as well as the receiver? Doing so would ensure that the service connection is closed deterministically rather than waiting for it to timeout and be force-closed.